# Complex supremum function is strictly monotone

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I'm having great troubles to solve the following exercise:

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disc. 
For $0\leq r < 1$ is $$M(r):=\sup\limits_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$$

1. Show that $M:[0,r)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and monotone
2. $f$ is not constant, so $M$ is strictly monotone

What I thought so far, but I don't know if it is correct:

Let $u,v\in D_r(0)$ and let $d(x,y):=M(x)-M(y)$. Then we have 
$$d(u,0)\leq d(v,0)$$ and $$d(0,v)- d(v,u)=d(0,v)-\sup|v-u|\leq d(u,0)$$
$$d(u,0)-d(v,0)\leq \sup|v-u|$$
So $d$ is continuous and therefore $M$ too.

Comment: Do you know the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: @mrf Yes, but I don't see, how I can deduce continuity out of it. I know if $f$ is not constant, then the maximum is on it's boundary, so $M$ must be monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the maximum modulus principle that $r \to M(r)$ is
is increasing, and also that it is strictly increasing if $f$
is not constant.

The continuity of $M$ is a consequence of the uniform continuity of $f$
on compact sets (the holomorphy is not needed here):

Let $r1, r_2 \in [0, 1)$ and $M(r_1) = \lvert f(r_1 e^{i \phi}) \rvert$. Then
$$
 M(r_1) \le \lvert f(r_1 e^{i \phi}) - f(r_2 e^{i \phi})\rvert + \lvert f(r_2 e^{i \phi}) \rvert \\
 \le \sup \{ \lvert f(z_1) - f(z_2) \rvert : \lvert z_1 - z_2\rvert \le \lvert r_1 - r_2\rvert \} + M(r_2) \, .
$$
By symmetry it follows that
$$ \tag{*}
 \lvert M(r_1) - M(r_2)\rvert \le \sup \{ \lvert f(z_1) - f(z_2)\rvert : \lvert z_1 - z_2 \rvert \le \lvert r_1 - r_2\rvert \} \, .
$$
Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\lvert z \rvert  \le r < 1$,
for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that the
RHS of $(*)$ is less than $\varepsilon$ for $r_1, r_2 \in [0, r]$
with $\lvert r_1 - r_2 \rvert < \delta$.