Non-constant holomorphic function defined on open disk $D(0,1)$

Let $f:D(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant holomorphic function. For each $r \in [0,1[$, define:
$$h(r)=\max\{|f(z)| : |z| = r\}$$
Show that h is $\textbf{strictly}$ increasing.

By Maximum Modulus Principle, for each $r \in [0,1[$:
\begin{align*}
\max_{z \ \in \ \overline{D}(0,r)}{|f(z)|}= \max_{z \  \in \ \partial D(0,r)}{|f(z)|}
\end{align*}
So if $h$ was not strictly increasing, there would exist $0<r_1<r_2<1$ such that:
$$h(r_1)\geq h(r_2) \underbrace{\implies}_{MMP}h(r_1)=h(r_2)$$
But now we'd have that $h$ would be constant on $[r_1,r_2]$. I don't know how to proceed form here, but I guess that identity's theorem coulb be used from here.
Any suggestions? Is there another way without using Maximum Modulus Principle?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1757076/42969

Take $r_1,r_2\in[0,1]$ such that $r_1<r_2$.
We know that $h(r_2)$ is attained at the circle of radius $r_2$.
If $h(r_1)=h(r_2)$ then there would exist some $x_1$ in the circle of radius $r_1$, and thus on the interior of the disk of radius $r_2$, which attains that maximum too.
By the Maximum Modulus Principle, $f$ is constant on the disk of radius $r_2$, and by the Identity Principle it must be constant on the unit disk too, a contradiction.

The maximum of $|f|$ on $\overline {D(0,r_2)}$ is attained at some point on its boundary. If $h(r_1)=h(r_2)$ the maximum would also be attined  at some point with $|z|=r_1$. By Maximum Modulus principle this implies that $f$ is a  constant on $D(0,r_2)$, hence also on $D(0,1)$.
